# How can I add my .sln file to my Jump List for Visual Studio (Windows 7)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, jump-list

This very well my be a [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com) question, however it's directly related to my programming environment so I thought I would ask here to see if another developer has solved this issue.

I would like to add my most commonly opened solutions to my [Jump List](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Using-Jump-Lists-to-open-programs-and-items) for Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7. I've fiddled with the recommended methods of doing so I've found around the web, but I haven't had any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You first need to edit your registry so that your solution file is associated with visual studio directly (i.e. not through the version selector)

[Article on how to do this](http://einsteintech.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!89E05724AF67A39E!744.entry).

Once you do that then you can pin it to whatever version of VS you have.

Comment: The registry hack didn't quite work, but it set me on the right path.  Only problem is that I still have old solutions that require a different version, but I'll cross that bridge later.

Comment: I'm having this issue with VS 2015 in Windows 8.1. The linked article is no longer valid.

Answer (score 5):

I figured one way to do it (if you don't want to mess with the registry), but ultimately I went with the other answer.

I had to drag the solution file to the taskbar itself. The OS knows to add VSLauncher to the taskbar and pin it to it.

The problem I was having was I was trying to drag it onto the visual studio 2008 application icon I had pinned to the desktop.

Comment: @blesh: You can accept your own answer to let others know that this is the solution that worked for you.

Comment: tells me I have to wait two days. Hopefully my memory can hold out. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's an [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/043d63da-f270-448a-8a68-5310bc53fbf0) that adds jump list support to Visual Studio 2008.